# freeBSD bootable CD/USB from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, cd

How to create bootable CD or USB (preferably) from Ubuntu?

I tried FreeBSD-8.1-RELEASE-i386-memstick.img from freeBSD.org with ubuntu service: Startup Disk Creator - but it fails saying: "Installation failed".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, unetbootin did the trick.