# How to Create FreeBSD 10 bootable in Ubuntu 14.04.01?

Tags: boot, usb-creator, bsd

I want install FreeBSD 10 ,
 how to create USB Bootable ?
i tried  **Unitbooten**  but its Not working [This Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18778/freebsd-bootable-cd-usb-from-ubuntu)  
please Help !!!

Answer (score 3):

I think we can use dd command to make the usb stick bootable. please try the command below.

```
#dd bs=4M if=freebsd.iso of=/dev/sdX && sync
```

where /dev/sdX is your usb drive device id.

Comment: Hello, the Command is not working..

Comment: @Ashu you have to be "super user" to run the "dd" command. so try the same command with "sudo" before everything,or just type "su".Type in your root password and be logged in as root,navigate to where the **.iso** is and just run the command as you see above.